# JQuery Validate Plugin Debug New Additional Method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to figure out why our form can still be submitted even if a user uses gmail.com email address as per our additional method called `checkDomain`.

I'd like to see real time at what point we're true and at what point we're false as that should clear it up, but I'm drawing a blank on how to `console.log` our value. How can we do that?

```
$.validator.addMethod('checkDomain', function (value) { 
    return /^([\w-.]+@(?!gmail\.com)(?!yahoo\.com)(?!hotmail\.com)([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/.test(value);
}, 'Please provide a business email.');

/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/


$(formId).validate({
    rules: {
        FirstName: "required",
        LastName: "required",
        Company: "required",
        Primary_Interest__c: "required",
        Company_Size__c: "required",
        Phone: "required",
        Email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            checkDomain: true
        },
        MktoCompanyNotes: "required"
        console.log(checkDomain);
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rules` object should only contain `key:value` pairs representing the field name(s) and corresponding rules with parameters.  You cannot just stick a line of JavaScript in the there and not expect things to break.

> I'm drawing a blank on how to `console.log` our value. How can we do that?

Have you tried doing it within the function itself, which already contains the field's value?

```
$.validator.addMethod('checkDomain', function (value) { 
    console.log(value); // <- HERE
    return /^([\w-.]+@(?!gmail\.com)(?!yahoo\.com)(?!hotmail\.com)([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/.test(value);
}, 'Please provide a business email.');
```

And your custom rule appears to be working perfectly fine:

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/7hvxe9gd/](https://jsfiddle.net/7hvxe9gd/)**

Comment: Hi @Sparky , thanks for the reply. Great call. I think I was staring too long. It turns out that wasn't the issue as per our console.log check. 

You're right, they're working, but for some reason one form is applying though the submit button isn't disabled.

Comment: Based on comment and code in OP, nobody can know what’s wrong.

Comment: I can include more — what should I include in the original post? The two forms are identical though though their container is not as per the `(formid)` . Can we continue this in chat so as to not muddy up this thread? I'll come in after and clean it up.

Comment: @user313573, what can you include?  Include the code that is causing the actual issue.  Right now, your OP contains code that is working and your comments indicate some other problem.  Now I'm confused about what you're talking about.  Click the edit link on your OP and make an *addendum* that **clearly describes the issue and shows the relevant code**.  Please refrain from posting a question that morphs into something else entirely... it's unhelpful to future readers and it's very unfair to people posting answers to have them rendered useless by suddenly changing the question.